# View history of anonymous users

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet, which is accessible (only view) by anyone who has the link. I want to have an overview of every timestamp the document was opened by an not-logged-in (= anonymous) user. How can I do this?

Comment: @Rubén yeah I saw that thread and it's dated from 2011 and the solution there is with a third party that didn't seem to work for me

Comment: I believe that this is not _strictly_ a duplicate. This question is specific to Google Spreadsheet (and as such can use a Spreadsheet-specific solution), while the linked answer is generic to all Google Drive documents.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal It's a duplicate because the answer is the same. While this question is specific to Google Sheets., AFAIK there aren't specific solutions. i.e. onEdit simple/installable triggers and onChange installable triggers which are specific for spreadsheets, can't be used to log spreadsheet views from anonymous users.

Comment: The onOpen trigger besides being available for spreadsheets it's also available for documents, presentations and forms (edit view)

Comment: @Rubén I guess you're right, after how this question has evolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was hoping to answer your question with a Google Apps script. There is an [onOpen](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) event, but it fires only on users *that have edit access* to the spreadsheet. Since your users only have *view* access, a script won't work like that.

If you're willing to give anonymous users edit access (which will let *anyone* in the world who knows the URL edit), you could log all visits to your spreadsheet to a separate Access Log spreadsheet.:

1. Create a new spreadsheet document, and create a sheet (tab) on it, let's call the sheet *Access Log*.
2. Note the ID of the created spreadsheet. You'll find the ID in the browser's location bar:
   [image: Spreadsheet ID in URL bar]
3. Open the spreadsheet you're going to make public
4. Go to *Tools → Script editor*
5. Paste the following script into the script editor window:

   `function onOpen() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("11evsXXXXXXXXXXXXXX8Xt3E6vI").getSheetByName("Access Log"); 
   sheet.appendRow([new Date(), Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()]);
   }`
     ... replacing `11evsXXXXXXXXXXXXXX8Xt3E6vI`is the ID you copied in step 2
6. Click the *Run* button, a dialog will open asking you to grant access to the script (you only have to do this once)
7. Close the script editor window

From now on, anyone visiting your sheet will cause a line to be appended to the *Access Log* sheet.

I have setup [an example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11evsXmwjypqxYS3IYQ3ZwxG30BPI5N7vPtn8Xt3E6vI/edit?usp=sharing) to demonstrate. It does not allow anonymous users to edit, so it will not log anything, but feel free to copy it and use it as a basis for your own sheet.

The script explained:
The `onOpen` function name tells Google Sheet to run this script whenever the sheet is opened by someone. `...openById(...).getSheetByName("Access Log")` gives a reference to the sheet named *Access Log* in the separate spreadsheet document. Finally, `sheet.appendRow([...])` appends a new row to the log sheet, with a timestamp and the current user's email address (which in case of an anonymous user will be empty).

---

An alternative solution is to use a URL shortener with analytics, such as [bit.ly](https://bit.ly). It will allow you to make a short link that you will distribute to your users. When your users visit the link, they will be redirected to your spreadsheet.
By logging in to bit.ly, you will be able to see simple click stats.

Now, obviously, this will only work if your users *only use the short link* when visiting your spreadsheet. You won't be able to count anyone going directly to your spreadsheet by its long URL.

Comment: Or how about this: can the log be copied automatically to a different sheet in my drive folder, then wipe the log data on the original sheet that the anonymous user has access to?

Comment: See revised answer. The script now logs to a separate spreadsheet document.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, that's not possible, because anonymous users are not included in the log.

- enter your Drive - **https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive**
- find your file and check log pressing ⓘ button to see what is logged:

[image]

**alternatives are - [bitly](https://bit.ly) statistics or custom script**